# How to write a valid JSON file in Java?

Tags: java, json, file

I am getting the following JSON object from postman:

```
{"Name":"one","age":"22"}
```

If file is empty,it should paste like:

```
[{"Name":"one","age":"22"}]
```

else:

```
[{"Name":"one","age":"22"},{"Name":"one","age":"22"}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: can u make question bit clear

Comment: Can you write smore more details, how are you receiving the JSON HTTP? What is the error, what code did you write? Check here for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Do you have the code that write this JSON?If you have, look in your code where is the response and problably you can see the difference about the result. When you have more than one registers, the response is returning a list / array and when you have only one is returning this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little unclear but you want to pass back a Collection or an array for the square brackets [].

Roughly speaking {} maps to a java object. 
[] maps to a java Collection such as an ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

Because you didn't mention too much detail, I assumed that you can always receive the HTTP response (such as HTTP status code is 200.) and the response is always a valid JSON string.

A simple way to achieve this is using a `List<Map<String, Object>>` for data manipulation. Following code snippet (without considering any exception handling) shows how to use the `List<Map<String, Object>>` for reading and writing file with it.

**Sample code (written in Java 8 with Jackson JSON parser)**

```
List<Map<String, Object>> jsonList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

Path path = Paths.get("json_result.txt"); //this file already existed

//read file and save content into jsonList
Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(path);
lines.forEach(line -> {
   try {
       jsonList.addAll(mapper.readValue(line, new TypeReference<List<Map<String, Object>>>(){}));
   }
   ...
}

//add new response string into jsonList and write to file
String responseStr = "{\"Name\":\"one\",\"age\":\"22\"}";
jsonList.add(mapper.readValue(responseStr, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){}));
Files.write(path, jsonList.toString().getBytes());
```